# How is comparing $|E|^2$ to $|H|^2$ relevant?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

I am reading one article that compares two kinds of electromagnetic surface waves, but the following figure confuses me:

[image]

Why instead of comparing  $|E|^2$  and  $|E|^2$ do they compare $|E|^2$ and  $|H|^2$? Is it somehow better? Or maybe is it a manipulation? Or maybe it is more convenient?

Articles DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.snb.2012.07.015

Answer (score 1):

They’re trying to show where the energy is located. They show H vs E for the two waves because the two different types of waves are just different.

There’s a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_plasmon_polariton) that discusses the role of the H field in surface plasmon polariton (SPP) waves, which are always transverse magnetic (TM) mode.

Comment: Can you save the rest of us a few seconds and include a link to the Wikipedia article you are referring to?

Comment: @rob Added link, sorry for trouble.  Never quite sure when it's OK to add a Wikipedia link...

Comment: No trouble! I think that anytime you feel it's appropriate to refer to a Wikipedia article, it's better to use a link than something fragile like a search term.